# Returning output from excel solver in VBA, without changing values in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I want to solve a change of state equation that looks like this:

```
tension = constant + numerator / tension^2
```

This can be solved in sheet simply with the objective of minimising the difference between some initial tension `tension_init` and `tension_formula` expressed as `=constant + numerator / tension_init^2` by changing the variable `tension_init`. The difference is the formula `=ABS(tension_init - tension_formula)`.

I want to be able to input these parameters in a vba function and then get the final value for `tension_init` as an output. I'd like to do this *without* changing the values in the sheet, if possible.

I'm attempting to do this with the following vba function:

```
Public Function GetTensionChange(constant As Double, numerator As Double, tension_init As Range, tension_difference As Range) As Double

SolverOk SetCell:=tension_difference, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=tension_init

SolverSolve

End Function
```

However, I'm struggling to understand how to return a solved value from the solver. I get a return of 0 which I think means a solution has been found.

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Solver changes the worksheet values. If you don't want that, you need to reset them to their original values programmatically.